# Sql - How to update a column for all rows?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
$sql = "UPDATE debtorsmaster SET  name='" . $_POST['CustName'] . "',
address1='" . $_POST['Address1'] . "',
address2='" . $_POST['Address2'] . "',
address3='" . $_POST['Address3'] . "',
```

How to change this to update to all rows

Comment: Like that (except for the trailing `,`), but preferably via using prepared statements and actually executing :)

Comment: But this does update all rows in the table.  That is not normally what one wants, but that is what your query does.

Comment: Without a WHERE clause, you'll update all rows.

Comment: BTW learn about prepared statements

Comment: Looks like that is not the qhole Statements, becaus the last character is a comma

Comment: As there is no where clause , the same statement can be used to update all the rows...you only need to remove the trailing ,

Comment: Actually this `UPDATE` is updating the columns `name, address1, address2, address3` for all the rows in the table `debtorsmaster`. And  as people commented without a `WHERE` clause you are updating all the rows, very rarely you want to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're not adding a WHERE statement all the rows will be updated. As noted in the above comments you have a trailing , which causes the query to be invalid.

Also it's adviced to use prepared statements to prevent SQL Injection.

```
$statement = $db->prepare("UPDATE `debtorsmaster` SET `name`=?, `address1`=?, `address2`=?, `address3`=?");
$statement->bind_param("ssss", $customerName, $address1, $address2, $address3);

$customerName = $_POST['CustName'];
$address1 = $_POST['Address1'];
$address2 = $_POST['Address2'];
$address3 = $_POST['Address3'];

$statement->execute();
```

EDIT: Above example is based on mysqli.